# paginate laravel 8 {{$con->links()}} not work

Tags: hyperlink, pagination

in blade page when I put {{$con->links()}} then it shows error. But when {{$con->links()}} removes from blade file it works properly, without any link for going next page.

Call to undefined method stdClass::links() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bluedream\resources\views\all_countries.blade.php)

In app service provider i already add
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
and in boot
Paginator::useBootstrap();

but still not work. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i cant even comment at your post. plus you didnt give enough info to debug.

so i try to answers.

Change

```
{{$con->links()}}
```

To

```
{{ $cons->links }}
```

Or

```
{!! $cons->links() !!}
```